# Escribir datos de JSON en input con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

**Lo que deberia hacer:** Tengo un formulario en HTML en el que al recargar la pagina los inputs deben quedar escritos con los datos anteriormente guardados.

**Lo que hace bien:** El JSON se crea correctamente y los datos se guardan (comprobado con console.log).

**Lo que hace mal**: Al recargar la pagina, en los inputs se escribe "undefined".

**JavaScript:**

```
function guardarDatos(){    
   let inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
   let inputSurname = document.getElementById("inputSurname").value;
   let inputAge = document.getElementById("inputAge").value;
   let inputEmail = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
   let inputTel = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;

let perfil =
'{' +
'"nombrePerfil":"' + inputName + '",' +
'"apellidoPerfil":"' + inputSurname + '",' +
'"edadPerfil":"' + inputAge + '",' +
'"emailPerfil":"' + inputEmail + '",' +
'"telPerfil":"' + inputTel +
'"}';

window.localStorage.setItem("perfil", perfil);

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
   let userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("perfil"));
console.log(localStorage.getItem("perfil")); //devuelve el string de los datos correctamente guardados
console.log(userProfile.inputName); //devuelve undefined
   document.getElementById("inputName").value = userProfile.inputName;
   document.getElementById("inputSurname").value = userProfile.inputSurname;
   document.getElementById("inputAge").value = userProfile.inputAge;
   document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = userProfile.inputEmail;
   document.getElementById("inputPhone").value = userProfile.inputTel;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores de los datos que obtienes del `localStorage` están mal. Debería ser así:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
   let userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("perfil"));
console.log(localStorage.getItem("perfil"));
console.log(userProfile.inputName); //devuelve undefined
   document.getElementById("inputName").value = userProfile.nombrePerfil;
   document.getElementById("inputSurname").value = userProfile.apellidoPerfil;
   document.getElementById("inputAge").value = userProfile.edadPerfil;
   document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = userProfile.emailPerfil;
   document.getElementById("inputPhone").value = userProfile.telPerfil;
});
```

Por cierto, no es necesario que compongas el texto del JSON que vas a guardar a mano. Puedes hacerlo con `JSON.stringify()`:

```
let perfil =
{
  nombrePerfil: inputName,
  apellidoPerfil: inputSurname,
  edadPerfil: inputAge,
  emailPerfil: inputEmail,
  telPerfil: inputTel
};

window.localStorage.setItem("perfil", JSON.stringify(perfil));
```

Comment: Tenes razón compañero, así funcionó. Gracias. Buen dato el de stringify